# Passing Query Parameters from HTML/JS App to Azure Server Script

Tags: javascript, sql, html, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am currently working on an HTML/JS App using Windows Azure Mobile Service.
I have two tables, one storing information about an attraction [attractionTable(attractionId, address,...)] and one keeping track of which user likes which attraction [favoriteAttractionTable(attractionId, userId, fav(bool))].

If the client wants to have a list of his favorite attractions there should only be one request to the server. On the server side I edited the read script of the favoriteAttractionTable to this:

```
function read(query, user, request) {

   var sql =
       "FROM routesTable rt, favoriteAttractionTable ft " +
        "WHERE rt.id = ft.routeId;";

    mssql.query(sql, {
        success: function(results) {
            request.respond(statusCodes.OK, results);
        }});

}
```

In my JavaScript Code I am using the following request

```
function loadFavoriteAttractions(){
    favTable = client.getTable("favoriteAttractionTable");
    var query = favTable.where({
            fav: true,
        userId : 0
        }).read().done(function (results) {
            console.log(results);
        }, function (err) {
            alert("Error: " + err);
        });
}
```

I basically get the information of all attractions that any user has added to his favorites but I want to modify the var sql in a way to receive only the ones related to the appropriate userId.

```
query.getComponents();
```

shows queryString: '((fav eq true) and (userId eq 0))' in my server script. 
But I am wondering how I can access this information?!

```
request.parameters.fav
```

is supposedly undefined.

Any advice is highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to access request parameters in the scripts, your best bet is to use the custom query string parameters, something like the code below:

```
function loadFavoriteAttractions(){
    favTable = client.getTable("favoriteAttractionTable");
    var query = favTable.read({
        fav: true,
        userId : 0
    }).done(function (results) {
        console.log(results);
    }, function (err) {
        alert("Error: " + err);
    });
}
```

Those parameters will be accessed via the `request.parameters` object on the server side.

If you're interested, here's more details: when you use the `where` method, you're passing some template object which will be converted into an [OData `$filter` expression](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v2-documentation/uri-conventions/#45_Filter_System_Query_Option_filter) that is passed to the server. The server will then parse that and convert it into the appropriate SQL `WHERE` clause to be sent to the database. So your original code will send a request similar to this one (spaces will be replaced with `%20`, but left them here for clarity):

```
GET .../tables/favoriteAttractionTable?$filter=((fav eq true) and (userId eq 0))
```

As you found out, you can access it via the `getComponents` function, but at that point you'll have to parse the expression yourself to retrieve the values of the comparisons. If you want to access some values passed by the client, as I mentioned the easiest way is to pass them as "normal" query-string parameters. In the code I sent, the request that will be sent will be similar to

```
GET .../tables/favoriteAttractionTable?fav=true&userId=0
```

And those values you can retrieve from the `request.parameters` directly (the type of the values will be strings, so if you want to treat them as numbers of Boolean values you'll need to do the appropriate conversion).